# Offsetting a dynamic range of data

Tags: vba, excel, offset, dynamic-values

I'm having trouble with something that seems very basic. My experience with vba is essentially nothing. I have a spreadsheet containing data imported from some csv files using a script I made. The script reads in the data then creates a master spreadsheet or overwrites the previous master spreadsheet. I would like to move this data one column over in the same script. The range of the data that needs to be moved changes every time the spreadsheet is updated as more data is added. I have included the following at the end of my code to do this, but I cannot get it to work.

```
Set myRange = Range(Cells(1, 1).Address(), Cells(lastRow, lastColumn).Address())

Range("myRange").Offset(,1)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Here is what I have now. I keep running into 'Run-time error 1004' on the 14th line.

```
Dim myRange As Range
Dim DefPath As String
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastColumn As Long

Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long

DefPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
Workbooks.Open Filename:=DefPath & "\SEM Master File"

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set myRange = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))
myRange.Offset(, lastColumn).Value = myRange.Value
```

Second Edit: Here is what I have so far. It compiles and runs, but instead of moving everything over one column as I expected it to it makes a copy of the columns and puts it in the columns next to the data already in the spreadsheet.

```
Sub Offset_Data()
Dim myRange As Range
Dim DefPath As String
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastColumn As Long

DefPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
Workbooks.Open ("SEM Master File.xlsx")

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set myRange = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))
myRange.Offset(, lastColumn).Value = myRange.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Try removing the `address()`?

Comment: The error I get is Compile Error: Expected: =

Comment: Oh. Just do `myRange.Offset(,1)`

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: lol you can tell I don't use offset XD. So apparently you need to do something with it. I just added `.select` to the end.

Comment: `Set myrange = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastcolumn)) |
myrange.Offset(, lastcolumn).Value = myrange.Value`

Comment: Still not working. See my edit for details.

Comment: Uhhhh, you're switching variables.............`lRow` then `lastRow` XD

Comment: My bad. That was left over from an earlier attempt.

Comment: Removed those lines and still getting an error.

Comment: Works for me (without opening the workbook). You might want to add an extension to your path.

Comment: you seem to be mixing up both lastRow and lastCol with lRow and lCol. you need to check which should be used for what as lastRow and lastColumn seem to be currently undefined. Also why not use "Set myRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange"

Comment: I no longer get any errors, but nothing happens to the spreadsheet.

Comment: You're **_still_** mixing variables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Offset_Data()
Dim myRange As Range
Dim DefPath As String
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastColumn As Long

DefPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
Workbooks.Open ("SEM Master File.xlsx")

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set myRange = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))
myRange.Offset(, lastColumn).Value = myRange.Value
myRange.ClearContents
End Sub
```